# Netty 4 beta1 memory consumption

Tags: java, netty

I noticed an large increase in memory consumption  (+70 mo) between Netty 4 Alpha 8 and Netty 4 Beta 1

Tested on Win7 with java 7 runtime.

Netty 4 alpha 8 code: https://github.com/ccheneau/Holmes/tree/b_netty_4_alpha_8/holmes-core/src/main/java/net/holmes/core/http

Netty 4 beta 1 code: https://github.com/ccheneau/Holmes/tree/b_netty_4/holmes-core/src/main/java/net/holmes/core/http

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: would you be able to provide us a heapdump and open an issue on the netty issue tracker ?

Comment: done
issue 1088 created

Answer (score 2):

In fact, memory delta is memory allocated by the new pooled byte buffer allocator.

Using UnpooledByteBufAllocator like this:

```
ServerBootstrap sb = ...
sb.childOption(ChannelOption.ALLOCATOR, UnpooledByteBufAllocator.HEAP_BY_DEFAULT);
```

reduces memory consumption but probably also perfs.